# How to use appendTo to display information instead of in an alert box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, append, appendto

I'm a newbie so thanks in advance for any help. 
I am setting up a simple geolocation page. 
Currently when I click a button, an alert popup box states the geolocation settings.

The problem - instead of the result popping up in a box, I need the geolocation info to display on the page itself.

I was told I need to use the appendTo element and I've tried many different ways but nothing happens.

Here is the current script:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Geolocation</title>

    <script
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.       
    js"</script>    

    <section>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#startGeo').click(checkLocation);

    function checkLocation() {

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getLocation, 
        locationFail);
    }
    else  {
        document.write('You do not have geolocation');
    }

    } 

    function getLocation(position) {
        var latitude = position.coords.latitute;
        var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        var accuracy = position.coords.accuracy;
        var timestamp = position.coords.timestamp;


    alert('latitude: ' + latitude + 'longitude: ' + longitude + 
    'accuracy: ' + accuracy + 'timestamp: ' + timestamp);

    }

    function locationFail() {
    document.write('We did not get your location. Please check your  
    settings.')
    }

    });


    </script>

    </head>

    <body>

    <button id="startGeo">Click here to check your geolocation 
    abilities</button>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a container in your html

```
<div id="geoDisplay"></div>
```

Then create an element containing the geolocation and append it to the new container.

```
$('<div>latitude: ' + latitude + ' longitude: ' + longitude + 
' accuracy: ' + accuracy + ' timestamp: ' + timestamp + '</div>')
  .appendTo($('#geoDisplay'));
```

Now every time you click the button, it will append a div containing the geolocation information.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure if I need to post something somewhere else but I wanted to say thank you for everyone's responses. I tried this first suggestion and it worked! Thanks very much, what a great forum this is.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way of using [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/), which is very similar to appendTo, just with a different syntax:

```
$('body').append('latitude: ' + latitude + 'longitude: ' + longitude + 'accuracy: ' + accuracy + 'timestamp: ' + timestamp);
```

Comment: `$(body)` does not work, but `$(document.body)` and `$('body')` does.

Answer (score 1):

Insert a `<p class="data"></p>`   in your document

**Replace:**

```
alert('latitude: ' + latitude + 'longitude: ' + longitude + 
    'accuracy: ' + accuracy + 'timestamp: ' + timestamp);

    }
```

**With:**

```
$('.data').html('latitude: ' + latitude + 'longitude: ' + longitude + 
    'accuracy: ' + accuracy + 'timestamp: ' + timestamp);

    }
```

Comment: This is the much shorter answer to my jquery answer +1

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an element and add it to your DOM. For example:

```
var coordlabel = '<label>latitude: ' + latitude + 'longitude: ' + longitude + 
'accuracy: ' + accuracy + 'timestamp: ' + timestamp + '</label>';
$('body').append(coordlabel);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are asking how to get your string:

```
'latitude: ' + latitude + 'longitude: ' + longitude + 'accuracy: ' + accuracy + 'timestamp: ' + timestamp
```

inside an existing node on the DOM.

If this is the case, then please read the remaining information in this post because there are some things you need to know.

- **DOM** stands for the Document Object Model.
- **Nodes** are your html Elements that can be manipulated by Javascript using selectors. Example. JQUERY: `$('#element')` is a node selector.

If you are wanting to use Jquery to output your string generated by javascript then you would do:

```
var str = 'latitude: ' + latitude + 'longitude: ' + longitude + 'accuracy: ' + accuracy + 'timestamp: ' + timestamp;
$('#element').text(str);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/amLtprmt/

This will not append the Node, i do not believe that is what you were trying to do.

To do this in native JavaScript you would do:

```
var node = document.getElementById('element');
var str = 'latitude: ' + latitude + 'longitude: ' + longitude + 'accuracy: '       + accuracy + 'timestamp: ' + timestamp;
node.innerHTML = '';
node.appendChild(document.createTextNode(str));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/56tp7te1/

This is assuming your html looks similar to:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id='element'></div>
</body>
</html>
```